# remove changesets

Tags: git, gerrit

Is it possible to remove abandoned changeset via web ui or ssh command? I have rather big amount of abandoned changes, that I definitely do need and they just clutters search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this is not possible currently.  You can filter these out of your search results using 'status:open' or 'status:merged', but there is no way to permanently delete changesets in Gerrit at this time.

Comment: I'm not aware of any plans for this.  You can bring it up on the Gerrit mailing list at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/repo-discuss.  The SQL commands would change drastically from one release to another, and there would be other changes you'd need to make at the repository level to completely remove a change set.